# SQL запрос для каждого - все

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, mysqli

```
TABLE  sport(Name TEXT, Surname TEXT, Num TEXT, Vid TEXT, Mark REAL, Shtraf REAL)
```

Имя, фамилия, номер, вид спорта, очки, штрафы.

Как для каждой пары имя,фамилия вывести все виды спорта, где он принимал участие?

Comment: Зачем теги разных СУБД?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov +- синтаксис похож
может кто-то поможет))

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не совсем понятно, в каком виде должен быть выведен результат, но если, например, все значения в одном поле, то можно примерно так (MySQL):

```
SELECT `Name`, `Surname`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Vid`) FROM `sport` GROUP BY `Name`, `Surname`
```